How do i read the embed files from a pdf (without an external lib)
I would like to develop a console application in Visual Studio that can read embedded files from a PDF. While I am aware that there are various libraries available to simplify this process, I am interested in implementing the functionality myself to deepen my understanding of PDF file structures and handling embedded content.
I've searched for information, but I haven't been able to find anything.

What is the question? Asking for tutorials etc is off topic on SO.

@KJ There is no question asked, though. Not really, at least. Yes, the title hints to what the question is but still: there is nothing really to work with.

@KJ Sounds like an answer to me ...

@KJ "with a plain text decimal value /Length #####" - Often, yes, but a number of PDF creators instead have the length in an indirect object.

Ah, indeed, I only saw your second comment, not the first one...

You can download the PDF standard for free here:
https://pdfa.org/resource/iso-32000-2/#
Once you've read all the objects in the PDF, finding and extracting the embedded files is easy. The first part isn't, though.

Mind you: That's a PDF Standard. - The great thing about Standards is: there are so many of them.

@Fildor "That's a PDF Standard." - Well, but ISO 32000-2 arguably is the most relevant PDF standard nowadays. It encompasses (mostly) ISO 32000-1, and the PDF References before that weren't normative in nature anyways.

@mkl exactly. So, it depends how widely compatible you want/need to be. Usually I'd expect the named standard to be enough (nowadays). But if you are working with legacy data you might still be in trouble. - Just as I have been. G - glad that nightmare is over.

@Fildor "So, it depends how widely compatible you want/need to be." - As long as the question does not mention anything else, I assume files that are compliant to the PDF spec ;) , and that's been ISO 32000 since 2008. If the OP's use case differs, they should say so. (But you are right, there were some really awe-inspiring interpretations of the format PDF in the old days...)
